# pthread_mutex_init result in Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, database, pthreads, mutex

I'm a college student learning how to deal with threads and databases.
Overall, I'm trying to make a function that will take a list of locks, see if the current lock the program is handling is in the list, and mutex lock that lock.
Currently, I am having issues initializing the *locks, but every time I do so, I get a segmentation error (core dump).
I already try using the different ways of initializing the mutex lock:
`&locks->lock  = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`
as well as using : `pthread_mutex_init(&locks->lock, NULL);`

on the .h file, it contains

```
typedef struct {
char *table;
pthrad_mutex_t lock;} TableLock;
```

main file:

```
static pthread_mutex_t lock_on_locks;
static int active_tables = 0;
static TableLock *locks = NULL;

// Table locking functions
void sudba_lock(char *table) {
  sleep(2);
  if (locks == NULL) {
    my_realloc(locks, sizeof(TableLock));
    }
  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_on_locks);
  char table_name[strlen(table) + 1];
  table_name[strlen(table)] = '\0';
  sprintf(table_name, "%s", table);
  if (active_tables == 0) {
    pthread_mutex_init(&locks->lock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&locks->lock);
    locks[active_tables].table = table_name;
    active_tables++;
  }
```

the my_realloc function is this:

```
void *my_realloc(void *ptr, size_t size) {
    void *result = malloc(size);
    if(!result) abort();
    return result
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: regarding: `my_realloc(locks, sizeof(TableLock));`  The `TableLock` is a pointer, so `sizeof(TableLock)` will return a value of  4 or 8 (depending on the underlying hardware architecture,  The code needs to keep track of the current number of 'locks' and add one to that number before calling: `realloc()`.

Comment: regarding: `if(!result) abort()`  This leaves an allocation of memory, resulting in a memory leak.  Suggest passing the ( pointer to the allocated memory) to `free()` before exiting.   However, every time you call `malloc()`  the parameter `ptr` is not being free'd, so every time that function is called, another memory leak occurs

Comment: regarding: `my_realloc(locks, sizeof(TableLock));`  The function: `my_realloc()` returns the pointer to the just allocated memory,  BUT that returned pointer is never actually assigned to the variable `locks`

Comment: regarding: `table_name[strlen(table)] = '\0';`  the function: `strlen()` only works when the char array `table[]` is ALREADY NUL terminated.  Otherwise the result is undefined behavior.  Writing to whereever a NUL byte was encountered is a good way to cause a seg fault event.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problems and help you debug them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your crash has nothing to do with `pthread_mutex_lock`; it's just that you're passing a null pointer to it because you didn't save the result of `realloc`. Where you have:

```
my_realloc(locks, sizeof(TableLock));
```

it should be:

```
locks = my_realloc(locks, sizeof(TableLock));
```

But I'm not clear why you're allocating it anyway since this looks like a single-instance lock. Normally locks either have static storage duration or exist *inside some structure* you're allocating (whose contents they'll protect). Allocating an individual lock by itself is a code smell.

There are a lot of other things that look wrong with your code too, independent of the crash.